# How to add IFRAME with javascript to ajax loaded content

Tags: javascript, ajax, iframe, dynamic

How can I add an IFRAME with javascript to ajax refreshed content ? Let's say I have something like this:

```
$('#bar').delegate('.scroll-content-item span a', 'click', function() {
    var object_id = $(this).parent().attr("class");
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/myfunction.php",
        data: "action=object_id=" + object_id,
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data){
            $('.info').html(data['html']);                
        }
    });
    return false;
});
```

So I've tried adding this code on success :

```
            document.write('<IFRAME vspace=0 height=71 style="padding:10px" marginHeight=5 src="" frameBorder=0 width=54 name="pliggit" scrolling=no><script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script><script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:"b24b6378-26a9-435c-ac5f-8aee4f59529c"});</script></IFRAME>');
```

But I'm getting `Unterminated string literal`.

Comment: There are no child tags on an iframe - thus trying to add a script will not work.

Answer (score 0):

it's still early, but have you tried quoting your attributes?

or you could create your iframe in javascript:

```
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.setAttribute('vspace', '0');
```

etc.. ?

Comment: but inserting raw js is not prohibited as a whole ? Cuz I've started thinking that maybe I need to specify path to html with js as a source. I will try quoting attributes right now. And what about creating with js - I insert my code with innerhtml ?

Comment: you can append your scripts with var myscript = document.createElement('script'); myscript.src="http://path.to/script.js";   I also noticed that the script your referencing (at least 1) throws about 200 errors in linting.

Comment: Is there any reason that you are committed to using an iframe (because as I said, it was early and it didn't dawn on me that there are no child tags in an iframe [thx scunliffe].)?

Comment: what do you mean by child tags ?

Comment: It means that you can't shove a <script> tag (or any other tags) into an <iframe> element.

Comment: right, you can create an iframe with content by using: 
<iframe name="Frame1" src="frame.htm" >
</iframe>

or add an element by using:

<a href="http://www.google.com" target="Frame1">Go to google</a>

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't like the `</script>` tag. I'm still looking for a js answer to encode a block of code so that Javascript doesn't barf.